# rails 4 simple form association translation lookup (i18n)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, simple-form

here's something that has annoyed me for some time, and I couldn't find a solution yet.
Suppose I have a form with

```
f.association :driver
```

,then I expect Simple Form to look this up in `de.yml` under:

```
de:
  activerecord:
    models:
      driver: Fahrer
```

but it doesn't. I could copy this key to

```
de:
  activerecord:  
    attributes:  
      bus:  
        driver: Fahrer
```

but that's not DRY...
help?